Spawn XACRO File on Gazebo Harmonic & ROS2 Jazzy
I am trying to spawn a xacro file on gazebo harmonic (ros2 jazzy).
I have found this guide on how to spawn urdf and works fine: https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/spawn_urdf/
It also says to follow a ros2 guide in order to spawn a xacro file but I can not make it work.
(If you have a xacro representation of a robot model, you can turn the xacro file into a URDF file using the xacro package: see this tutorial for more information.)
On that tutorial is has instruction how to make robot state publisher publish xacro file and works fine, i tried it out (works with rviz).
Does anybode have any ideas on how to spawn a xacro robot?
Is there a package for gazebo harmonic that can spawn a robot using the robot_state_publiser topic like it has for gazebo classic?
Thank you!

quick update:
Here is the code that works for me on ROS2 Jazzy and Gazebo Harmonic.
It runs robot_state_publisher to publish my XACRO file and then spawns the robot in Gazebo based on the robot_description topic that the robot_state_publisher creates.
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_path
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import launch_ros.descriptions
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

    # Get the urdf/xacro file path
    path_to_urdf = get_package_share_path('simulation_pkg')/'description'/'robot_urdf.xacro'
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{
            'robot_description': ParameterValue(Command(['xacro ', str(path_to_urdf)]), value_type=str)
        }]
    )

    # Use your custom Gazebo world (optional). Replace 'empty.sdf' with the word "world" (no "" needed)
    # world = os.path.join(
    #     get_package_share_directory(package_name), "worlds", "empty_world.sdf"
    # )

    gz_sim = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            [
                os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory("ros_gz_sim"),
                    "launch",
                    "gz_sim.launch.py",
                )
            ]
        ),
        launch_arguments={"gz_args": [" -r -v 4 ", 'empty.sdf']}.items(),
    )

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo
    spawn_entity = Node(
        package="ros_gz_sim",
        executable="create",
        arguments=[
            "-name",
            "robot1",
            "-topic",
            "/robot_description",
            "-x",
            "0",
            "-y",
            "0",
            "-z",
            "1.4",
        ],
        output="screen",
    )

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher, gz_sim, spawn_entity
    ])


I have something like the following working in humble with ignition(gazebo fortress). This was derived from the official documentation found here https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages/
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import launch_ros.descriptions

def generate_launch_description():

    # Set ignition resource path
    ign_resource_path = SetEnvironmentVariable(
        name="IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH",
        value=[
            os.path.join(package_name, "worlds"),
            ":" + str(Path(desc_package_name).parent.resolve()),
        ],
    )

    xacro_file = os. path.join("desc_pkg", "urdf", "robot.urdf.xacro")

    robot_description_config = Command(
        ["xacro ", xacro_file, " sim_mode:=", use_sim_time]
    )

    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {
        "robot_description": launch_ros.descriptions.ParameterValue(
            robot_description_config, value_type=str
        ),
        "use_sim_time": use_sim_time,
    }

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[params],
    )

    world = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_name), "worlds", "empty_world.sdf"
    )

    gz_sim = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            [
                os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory("ros_gz_sim"),
                    "launch",
                    "gz_sim.launch.py",
                )
            ]
        ),
        launch_arguments={"gz_args": [" -r -v 4 ", world]}.items(),
    )

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo
    spawn_entity = Node(
        package="ros_gz_sim",
        executable="create",
        arguments=[
            "-name",
            "groundhog",
            "-topic",
            "/robot_description",
            "-x",
            "0",
            "-y",
            "0",
            "-z",
            "1.4",
        ],
        output="screen",
    )

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "use_sim_time", default_value="true", description="Use sim time if true"
            ),
            ign_resource_path
            robot_state_publisher_node,
            gz_sim,
            spawn_entity,
        ]
    )





Looks promising. So this is used to spawn the robot using robot_description like in the gazebo classic right? I hope it will work for ros2 jazzy too. I will try it out in the next day and give everyone an update. Thank you!
